# How to boot from live USB to reinstall Ubuntu on iMac running Ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: boot

I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04lts on an iMac running Ubuntu 20.04lts as the only os. I cannot figure out how to access boot priority menu to allow the system to boot from USB drive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. before starting your iMac plug in the USB key
2. after starting the iMac press and hold the `alt` key immediately until boot menu with drives appears
3. select the USB key and you're ready to go.

Comment: I've tried that and nothing happens. It goes to a black screen with and underscore promp for a few seconds then to Ubuntu logo screen and boots to Ubuntu.

Comment: this article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796 tells you to start holding the `alt` key immediately after start. I advise to try it a couple of times to get it right - if you're unable to access Startup Manager - you may have damaged your UEFI firmware interface. Then google for resetting SMC on a Mac.

Comment: I tried what you said still not working. Is there anyway to reinstall UEFI firmware interface that you Know of? Is this even possible?